# Cannot access wcf service when trying to access it outside where wcf service runs

Tags: c#, wcf

My simple wcf runs correctly because when I try to create an application to wcf it returns the expected data, but when I am trying to run the application outside wcf service run, it gives error

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

wcf service web config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <configuration>

          <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
          </system.web>
          <system.serviceModel>
<services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.21.102:4424/Service1.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
            <behaviors>
              <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                  <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                  <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
              </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors> 
            <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
          </system.serviceModel>
         <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
          </system.webServer>

        </configuration>
```

client app config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4424/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I didm\n't touch or edit those things

Comment: Do you have a app.config for your application with the WCF configuration?

Comment: @Hyralex, I don't have, just a webconfig

Comment: @SHINHAN - Can you clarify what you mean by `application outside WCF`?  Are you trying to run the service without hosting it?  Or trying to connect to it from another computer via a client?

Comment: @Tim connect it from another computer via a client,

Comment: @SHINHAN - It could be one of any number of things.  Please post both your service config and your client config, and the code you're using to try and connect the client to the service.

Comment: You need to add an endpoint element for the class implementing `IService1` to your service web.config. Make sure to use the full class name including namespaces.

Comment: @EladLachmi, done that still the same

Comment: @EladLachmi - OP is using .NET 4.0, so the framework will use default endpoints if no endpoints are specified in the config file (or programatically).

Comment: @Tim - I know, but this assumes so many defaults that I always define my endpoints. This way me and other team members don`t get lost and spend a whole day debuging a service, which is using the wrong binding because that is the default.

Comment: @EladLachmi - I agree with the approach you use (it's the same one I use at work, but we started with WCF in 3.5 before default endpoints).  I was simply pointing out that the lack of defined endpoints was not the culprit in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, your service is defined to use `wsHttpBinding`, but your client is using `basicHttpBinding`.  The bindings need to match.

Second, The address in your client config is set to `localhost` - that means your client is looking for the service on the same machine the client is on.

For example, if your service is on a machine named MySever1 (for example), and you put the client (with the posted config) on a machine named MyClient1 (again, for example), it's going to look for the service on MyClient1 (localhost for the client).

Change the client endpoint to `http://192.168.21.102:4424/Service1.svc` and you should be able to connect, barring any firewall issues.

For example:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.21.102:4424/Service1.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

**EDIT**

In your service side config, do the following for the endpoint:

```
service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="WcfService1.IService1">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

In your client config:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.21.102:4424/Service1.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

Note that in the service endpoint declaration, the `address` attribute is blank - the location of the *.svc file be used to determine the actual address.  Secondly, change the binding to `basicHttpBinding` to match what the client will be calling.

In the client config, specify the full address of the service you are calling.

Comment: But when I try to rebuild the wcf solution and view in browser it gives me error "When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute. To fix this problem, specify a relative uri for endpoint 'http://192.168.21.102:4424/Service1.svc'.

Comment: I tried it already, and the client gives error "There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.21.102:4424/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details"

Comment: @SHINHAN - What does the inner exception say?

Comment: InnerException = {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.21.102:4424"}

Comment: when I try to navigate the site to browser still cant access it but when change it to localhost it is ok